# jQuery - two linked events that disable self and enable the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need  that once event1 triggers, it activates event2 and disable self, and vice versa. I'm having trouble with the last step, because when I focus out, the input only briefly disappears.

```js
/**
 * Actions to be done once one of the div is clicked. 
 * It should hide the span, fade in the input, focus it, disable the self event and enable the input event.
 */
$('.range-wrapper').click(e => rangeClickEvent(e.target));

/**
 * Actions to be done once one of the input loses focus or the enter key is pressed. 
 * It should hide the input, fade in the span, reenable the click event on the wrapper and disable self.
 */
$('.range-wrapper input').on('focusout keyup', e => {
    if (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode != 13) {
        return;
    }
    rangeFocusOutEvent(e.target);
    $('.range-wrapper input').off('focusout keyup');
});

function rangeClickEvent(rangeElement) {
    $(rangeElement).children('span').hide();
    $(rangeElement).children('input').fadeIn(300).focus();
    $(rangeElement).off('click').removeClass('clickable');
}

function rangeFocusOutEvent(inputElement) {
    const parentDiv = $(inputElement).parent();
    $(inputElement).hide();
    $(parentDiv).children('span').fadeIn(300);
    setClickEventBack(parentDiv);
}

function setClickEventBack(rangeElement) {
    $(rangeElement).addClass('clickable');
    //line below - re-adding the click event causes trouble
    $(rangeElement).on('click', rangeClickEvent(rangeElement));
}
```

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/1j7fby49/12/

So basically clicking on the div hides the span and shows the input. Once I'm done with the input (focusout or enter key), it should hide the input and show the span again.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the function at the definition of the click handler rather than in its callback. Fix:

```
$(rangeElement).on('click', function() {rangeClickEvent(rangeElement)});
```

Comment: Thanks! That was my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you're looking for sort of placeholder mechanizm.
If so, allow me to simplify your code. As I see it, you don't need to `on` and `off` events.
I used `toggle` to show / hide elements but you can also use [`fadeToggle`](https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/).

```js
/**
 * Actions to be done once one of the div is clicked. 
 * It should hide the span, fade in the input, focus it, disable the self event and enable the input event.
 */
const rangeElement = $('.range-wrapper');
const input = rangeElement.find('input');
const span = rangeElement.find('span');

function toggle() {
  input.toggle().focus();
  span.toggle();
}

rangeElement.on('click', toggle);

/**
 * Actions to be done once one of the input loses focus or the enter key is pressed. 
 * It should hide the input, fade in the span, reenable the click event on the wrapper and disable self.
 */
$('.range-wrapper input')
  .on('keyup', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (e.type == 'keyup' && e.keyCode === 13) {
      $(this).blur();
    }
  })
  .on('focusout', function() {
    toggle();
    span.text(input.val() || 'Some Value')
  });

/* function rangeClickEvent(rangeElement) {
    $(rangeElement).children('span').hide();
    $(rangeElement).children('input').fadeIn(300).focus();
    $(rangeElement).off('click').removeClass('clickable');
}

function rangeFocusOutEvent(inputElement) {
    const parentDiv = $(inputElement).parent();
    $(inputElement).hide();
    $(parentDiv).children('span').fadeIn(300);
    setClickEventBack(parentDiv);
}

function setClickEventBack(rangeElement) {
    $(rangeElement).addClass('clickable');
    //line below - re-adding the click event causes trouble
    $(rangeElement).on('click', rangeClickEvent(rangeElement));
} */
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #eee;
}

.range-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 10vw;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 2rem;
}

.range-wrapper>label,
.range-wrapper>span {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.range-wrapper>label {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: x-small;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.range-wrapper>span {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-wrapper clickable">
  <label for="value">VALUE</label>
  <span>Some Value</span>
  <input type="text" name="value" id="value" hidden>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/19zde3my/17/

BTW, you can do almost all of it (except having the updated text in the span) using only css. Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/6h12qcwz/18/

Comment: Hey Mosh, yes that's what I was looking for. There's still a something weird in the sample you provided - when you press the enter key it just comes back to the input - the same that was happening to me in the line I said that was causing trouble - and by debugging I saw that both the keyup and focusout events were being called, thus it was triggering everything twice. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I separated the events so press on enter make the input focus out which as a result show / hide the elements. It's more clear to separate concerns IMHO.